# Line segment always has content zero

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am new to measure theory, and I got stuck on the first exercise.

> Show that every line segment has content zero.

Can someone help me as how to prove that something has content zero?

And one more doubt: Is measure $0$ same as content $0$?

My definition of content zero:

> Let $A$ be a bounded subset of a plane. The set $A$ is said to have **content zero** if  $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists $ a finite set of rectangles whose union contains $A$ and whose sum of areas doesnot exceed $\epsilon$.

Comment: The one more doubt: Yes, I think it is *in this case* ... **but** it is not the same according to definitions. In fact, a real set can have measure (Lebesgue, say) zero but  content not zero. I really don't understand that, as the content involves a functions which is not necessarily additive and  etc. Perhaps someone else can clear this up.

Comment: @DonAntonio But how to prove the content zero thing?

Comment: @Qw To attempt to answer that I would first have to be completely sure what "content" is, at least in this case...and I am not. Sorry.

Comment: @DonAntonio I have made my definition clear. Can you help now?

Comment: @Qw I'll try...

Comment: @DonAntonio. Note the word FINITE in the def'n of content-0 in the Q.

Comment: @user254665 Indeed so...and that's what screwed my efforts in this. I don't know how to do it **unless** some other condition (compactness, in fact) is put on $\;A\;$  or on some "slightly" bigger set containing it...

Comment: @Qw Have you people already studied compact sets, at least in the plane?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, we have.

Comment: @Qwerty Ok...but then I think the claim may be false, according to your definition, if the line segment isn't finite...unless you meant all the time the segment of line is a *finite* one.

Comment: @DonAntonio I thought a line segment _always_ meant a finite length of line!

Comment: @Qwerty Ok, though I'm not sure whether that's the most usual assumption. Then I think we can work out something. Hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As $\;A\;$ is a finite, bounded segment of line, we can parametrize it as

$$A=\left\{\;(x,\,f(x))\in\Bbb R^2\;/\;x\in[0,1]\;,\;\;f(x)\;\text{is a linear function}\;\right\}$$

Let us now take any countable sequence of intervals covering $\;\Bbb R\;$ , say $\;\left\{\;(p_n,\,p_n+1)\;\right\}\;$ (for example, you can take the rationals made into a sequence, and let us define now for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$

$$K_n:=\left\{\;\left(x,\,f(x)-\frac\epsilon{2^n}\right)\times\left(x,\,f(x)+\frac\epsilon{2^n}\right)\;/\;x\in(p_n,\,p_n+1)\;\right\}\subset\Bbb R^2$$

It's easy now to see that $\;A\subset\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n\;$ and that each $\;K_n\;$ is open. By compacticy of $\;A\;$ (why?) we get that there exists a finite sequence $\;n_1,n_2,...n_k\;$ of indexes s.t. $\;A\subset\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k K_{n_i}\;$, and

$$|A|\le\left|\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k K_{n_i}\right|\le\left|\bigcup\limits_{n\in\Bbb N}K_n\right|=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2\epsilon}{2^n}=\epsilon\,,\,\,\text{and we're done}$$

Note: even if $\;A\;$ is considered an "open" segment of line we can always "close" its endpoint(s) and make it closed.

Comment: I think the $e$ of $K_n$ should be $\epsilon$. Ain't I right?

Comment: @Qwerty Of course, thanks. Correcting the typo now.

Comment: And there should be a comma in the definition of $A$

Comment: Can I take $p_n=n$ ?

Comment: @Qwerty I guess that can't be bad...

Comment: The "why" $\to$ Since $A$ is bounded finite segment of a line, it is compact; so every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: @Qwerty Nice...but not quite: it is because we can assume *also* that $\;A\;$ is **closed**. If we had taken $\;\{(x,f(x))\;/\;x\in [0,1)\}\;$ , for example, then we get that line segment isn't closed and thus isn't compact.

Comment: So whats the complete answer to "why" ?

Comment: @Qwerty Why? Because we can assume $\;A\;$ is compact. Why? Because if it isn't closed (we're *given* it is bounded), then we can "enlarge it" or embed it in a closed, bounded...etc.

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for clarification..

Answer (score 2):

A rectangle with non-zero finite width and length is a bounded set so a finite union of them is also a bounded set and cannot cover an unbounded set such as a line.

When $S$ is a subset of the plane and $F$ is a family of open rectangles with $\cup F \supset S$ there is a countable (finite or infinite) $G\subset F$ such that $\cup G\supset S.$ For $S$ to have measure $0$ it means that the value of $\sum_{g\in G}A(g)$ can be arbitrarily small (where $A(g)$ is the area of $g.$)

Let $S=\mathbb R\times \{0\}.$ For $r>0$ let $$G(r)=\{(n,n+2)\times (-r2^{-|n|},r2^{-|n|}):n\in \mathbb Z\}.$$ Then $\cup G(r)\supset S$ and $\sum_{g\in G(r)}A(g)=8r$ which can be as close to $0$ as desired. So the measure of $S$ is $0.$ Any line can be obtained by rotating S about some point; the same rotation can be applied to any $G(r).$ So the measure of any line is $0.$

If you want only open rectangles whose sides are parallel to the co-ordinate axis: Let $g\in G(r)$ as above, with $A(g)=r2^{2-|n|}.$ Observe that if $R$ is a rotation then the image $R(g)$ can be covered by no more than $2^{|n|}(1+1/r)$ open rectangles with sides parallel to the axes rectangles, each with width and length $r2^{3-|n|}.$ Their areas add up to at most $$(r2^{3-|n|})^2\cdot (2^{|n|}(1+1/r))=2^{6-|n|}(r^2+r).$$ And note that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z}2^{6-|n|}(r^2+r)$ can be as small as desired.

Comment: I find the wording here extremely confusing and unclear..and some more spaces between letter/symbols and also between lines won't hurt. For example, what does "When $S$ is a subset of the plane and $F$ is a family of open rectangles with $\cup F \supset S$ there is a countable (finite or infinite) $G\subset F$ such that $\cup G\supset S$"  mean? Do you really want simply to say the plane is Lindelöf? And you seem to be talking of "measure zero", whereas the OP asked for "content zero" and he even added a definition. Observe the word **finite** there.